# Android show HTML on TextView method fromHtml

Tags: android, html, textview

I am trying to display HTML in my textview. I found this [page](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/) and it says to use .fromHtml. I get an error when I try to use it

```
TextView tvAbout = (TextView) window.findViewById(R.id.tvAbout);
Spanned about_text = Html.fromHtml(R.string.about_text);
tvAbout.setText(about_text);
```

Eclipse suggests I use `toHtml`. When I do that it then suggest I use `fromHtml`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `getString` before getting from `string.xml`

```
    Spanned about_text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Html.fromHtml`  expects a string parameter, while the parameter you have provided "R.string.about_text" is an integer ID. Thats the reason for your error.

So follow Hariharan's answer to correct it to get the text from that ID.

```
getString(R.string.about_text)
```